# Unable to add transition in d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want to add transition effect on vertical bar I designed in d3. I am new to d3,i have tried adding transition() method but didn't quiet work. My code is as follows-

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("rx", barRadius)
            .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
                 var drilledvalue;
                    try {
                        drilledvalue = JSON.parse(parent.$("#drills").val())[colIds[0]];
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    if (typeof drilledvalue !== 'undefined' && drilledvalue.length > 0 && drilledvalue.indexOf(d[columns[0]]) !== -1) {
                        return drillShade;
                    }
                if(typeof chartData[div]["transpose"] === "undefined" || chartData[div]["transpose"]=='N')
                {
                return getDrawColor(div, parseInt(i));//"url(#gradientBar_" + (d[columns[0]]).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '', 'gi') + ")";
                }
                else
                {
                    return color(0);
                }
            })
            // .attr("color_value", "steelblue")
            .attr("index_value", function(d, i) {
                return "index-" + d[columns[0]].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '', 'gi');
            })
            .attr("class", function(d, i) {
                return "bars-Bubble-index-" + d[columns[0]].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '', 'gi')+div;
            })
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d[columns[0]] + ":" + d[measure1];
            })
            .attr("onclick", fun)
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return x(d[columns[0]]);
            })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d[measure1]);
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return height - y(d[measure1]);
            });
```

I want bar graph to appear from underneath one graph at a time. Plz help.

Answer (score 2):

Without a live example , it is a bit hard to help you. But, having a look at your code, you should put the initial height at 0 and then set the final height after transition :

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
//all settings
.attr("height",0)
.transition()
.duration(1000)//1 second
.attr("height",function(d)( return height - y(d[measure1]);));
```

EDIT:

Sorry, of course it would come from the top, you need to rotate the bars. Also, you might have to re-assess the height calculation after applying the rotation

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    //all settings
    .attr("height",0)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(180,x,y)"); //note y must be the bottom of the chart
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)//1 second
    .attr("height",function(d)( return height - y(d[measure1]);));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yoann, your code worked...almost! Bar are appearing from top to bottom instead of bottom to top,may be because I have set view box attribute in svg. Can you suggest any solutions....